# Al enviar formdata como dato con ajax se envia un arreglo vacio

Tags: javascript, ajax, nodejs, formdata

estoy intentando enviar datos, entre ellos un archivo(es una imagen), pero al testear lo que envía el ajax me imprime las llaves de un arreglo vacio({}),estoy utilizando nodejs con jswebtokenizer, aquí esta mi código:

```
function publicar(){
var nombre_archivo =  document.getElementById('imagen').files[0].name;
var file = document.getElementById('imagen').files[0]
var descripcion = document.getElementById("desc").value
var id = localStorage.getItem("Id")
var categoria = document.getElementById("category").innerHTML
let formdata = new FormData()
formdata.append('imagen',file)
formdata.append('nombre_arch',nombre)
formdata.append('descripcion',descripcion)
formdata.append('categoria',categoria)
formdata.append('id',id)

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()

    xmlhttp.open('POST',url+"/informacion",true)
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data'); 
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("Id"));
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(formdata))
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            alert("se subio correctamente")

        }



}
```

Imprimo el resultado en el servidor

```
principal.post("/informacion",(req,res)=>{
console.log(req.body)

})
```

Comment: Tú declaras esto `var nombre_archivo =  document.getElementById('imagen').files[0].name;` pero envías esto `formdata.append('nombre_arch',nombre)`, modifica esa parte y comenta que te arroja.

Comment: me arrojo aun vacio

Comment: el `FormData` se envia directo, no necesita `JSON.stringify`

Comment: lo modifique sin el JSON.stringify pero aun me sigue imprimiendo vacio :(

Comment: Ya pude, pero como imprimo en el servidor lo que envie por formdata?

Comment: Podrías compartir como solucionaste que el FormData no se quede vacio, pasa que me esta pasando igual, le pongo un append y nunca le lleno los datos al FormData.

Comment: @DanielSantos es un poco antigua mi pregunta, pero en unos dias compartire mi solucion :)

Answer (score 0):

tenía el mismo problema. En mi caso el problema era muy simple, en mi formulario olvide darle un name a la etiqueta input.

HTML

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  id="target">
  <input type="file" id="data" name="data" >
  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="send">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

JS

```js
$("#target").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("target"));
    formData.append("nombre","valor");
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "carga.php",
        dataType: "html",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
})
```

PHP

```html
<?php

print_r($_FILES);

?>
```

Espero te sea útil